# WCF Service Complex Type access in client-The name obj does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have wcf service and have a service

```
 public Subscriber GetSubscriberDetails(int contactNo)
        {
            try
            {
                return obj.GetSubscriberDetails(contactNo);
            }
            catch (GasCylinderException ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<GasCylinderFault>(new GasCylinderFault { Message = ex.Message, ErrorDetails = ex.ToString() });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException("unexcepted error has occured:"+ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I have service reference to the mvc project but when i am accesing the service , the objext service returned is assigned to complex type, when i put debugger and check the obj it
"The name obj does not exist in the current context"

I have defined the complex type in seperate assembly with proper attribute as followas

```
  [DataContract]
    public class Subscriber
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ContactNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int NoOfCylindersUsed { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastDespatchedDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int NoOfCylindersAllocated { get; set; }
        public List<GasCylinderRequest> request { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Subscriber)
            {
                var that=obj as Subscriber;
                return (this.ContactNo == that.ContactNo) &&
                       (this.Name == that.Name) &&
                       (this.Address == that.Address) &&
                       (this.Year == that.Year) &&
                       (this.NoOfCylindersAllocated == that.NoOfCylindersAllocated) &&
                       (this.NoOfCylindersUsed == that.NoOfCylindersUsed) &&
                       (this.LastDespatchedDate == that.LastDespatchedDate) &&
                       (this.request == that.request);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i am unable figure out .any help would be appericiated

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a Suscriber object in your ASP.NET project ?

If you got "The name Suscriber does not exsist in the current context" try rightclick the Suscriber type then resolve -> using service reference.